# How to populate MySQL database with a HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, json, database, mysql-workbench

I have a project in which I have a login/sign up system and the users must be stored along with their information in a MySQL database. I am using MySQL workbench to graphically look at everything but I am brand new to MySQL and Workbench so I am not completely sure how to correctly populate a MySQL database by using a hashmap of objects (objects are users who each have a username, password and test scores). And I also then need to draw all these values from MySQL database when I am at a login page to check if such a user exists within that database, then proceed to the user page. I am working in AndroidStudio. So I guess in general what I am saying is if anyone can point me towards a right direction (whether it be a website, answered question, or just give me info about MySQL and how to work it in general and then with a hashmap) I would greatly appreciate that. Thank you very much in advance.
Edit: Or how would I input the fields from EditText into a JSON file and then read it into the database? Like I said before I am not sure exactly how to go about this

Comment: Are you using an ORM tool to access your database? like hibernate or Spring JPA?

Comment: Please provide any code examples you have. and you can find many examples online for a small web application development using Java.

Comment: The only real things I have installed and using regarding all the is MySQL itself and Workbench. I have started coding some sort of dataBaseHelper java class I saw in a video but I need to somehow put information into a JSON from EditText fields and then read it into a database or something like that. Like I said before I am brand new to this so I am not sure what SPRING or ORM tools are exactly. I might now but I am pretty noob at MySQL @Awad

Comment: @Coda759 thats absolutely fine, everybody has to start somewhere. 
I would just check out this https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-part-iii-integrating-mysql-database-and-jpa-81391404046a 
I hope it can give you some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a table in MySQL for your users to go in

A basic users table looks like:

```
create table users (
  userid varchar(16),
  password varchar(40)
);
```

If you have a list of established users already, the best way to get them into the DB is to create a batch file, like

```
insert into users (userid, password) values (('a','b'), ('c','d'), etc)
```

Then you can batch these commands into MySQL from a text file.

If not, create a prepared statement:

```
insert into users (userid, password) values (?,?)
```

and use that to insert all of your key-value values one by one.